# any idea why this vue app is not rendered

Tags: vue.js, flask

here is my flask `from flask import Flask,redirect,render_template

```
app=Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def home():
    return render_template('index.html')

if __name__=='__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

`
here is my index.html

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.js"></script>

    
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/app.js') }}"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="app">
        count is {{count}}
        
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

here is my vue component

```
const app = Vue.createApp({
  data() {
      return {
          count: 0
      }
  },
  methods: {
      incrementCount() {
          this.count++
      }
  }
})

app.mount('#app')
```

also my browser extension shows vue is not detected

i spent nearly few hours just trying to wrap my head around it

Answer (score 1):

Replace this

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3"></script>
```

Vue is not detected

Comment: yes i understood that but what do i replace it with? sorry i am using js and vue for the first time.